# Benefits of using Graphql in Magento 2

Tags: magento, graphql, magento2

Can someone explain the benefits of using Graphql in your Magento/Magento 2 site?

Is it really faster than a normal query or using collections. Because from what i see is that you still have to set/fetch all data in the resolver that was declared on the schema.graphql so that it will be available on every request.

Is it faster because each set of data is cached by graphql or is their a logic behind it that make it faster?

Like when you just need a name, description of a product you would just have to call getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(['name', 'description'])->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $id)->getFirstItem() inside your block wherein a graphql request the data will be fetch via the resolver which all the data of the product is being fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding about performance , GraphQL is normally faster than the equivalent REST API if the client needs to get a graph of data and assuming GraphQL API is implemented correctly . Otherwise ,it may easily lead to [N+1 loading problem](https://www.google.com/search?ei=DTpSXciJOcn_wAPtx7vIBg&q=graphql%20n%2B1%20loading%20problem&oq=graphql%20n%2B1%20loading%20problme&gs_l=psy-ab.3...0.0..15380...0.0..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz.hRKEpbkOUzk&ved=0ahUKEwiIxNzy_v7jAhXJP3AKHe3jDmkQ4dUDCAo&uact=5) which will make the API slow.

It is faster mainly because client only need to send one request to get the whole graph of the data while in the REST API , client need to send many HTTP requests separately to get the whole graph of data. The number of network round trip is reduced to one in GraphQL case and hence it is faster (Of course, it assumes that there is no single equivalent REST API to get this graph of data. )

In other words , if you only get a single record , you will not find there is much performance differences in the REST API and GraphQL API.

But besides performance , what GraphQL API offers is to allow user to get the exact fields and exact graph of data that they want which is difficult to be achieved in REST API.